# Como validar um formulário de Login no Ionic 3

Tags: ionic, formulário, asp.net-core, ionic3

Como validar um formulário de Login que contem EMAIL e SENHA no Ionic 3?
É necessário a criação de um novo componente para validar estes campos ?

Comment: Quando você fala validar é o que? Verificar se é email válido e senha tem X caracteres por exemplo ou ver se os dados batem?

Comment: Use o FormGroup de '@angular/forms';

Comment: Eduardo, exatamente isto.

Comment: Renan, vou tentar usa-lo

Answer (score 0):

As validações no Ionic 3 podem ser implementadas no próprio JS com uma funçao validaFormulario() ou com os Froms do angular.

Segue um tutorial de implementação de uma tela de login com FormBuilder que acredito ser a forma mais eficiente e elegante de validação de formulários.

https://robferguson.org/blog/2017/11/19/ionic-3-and-forms/